# MobX persistant store with Webpack hot reloading

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

Is there a way to use the webpack hot reloading functionality by CreateReactApp, while keeping the MobX store intact?

At the moment, at every refresh, my state is gone..

Comment: Have you looked at [mobx-starter](https://github.com/nightwolfz/mobx-starter)? It might give some inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

For this you can look into MobX-State-Tree (https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree)

This has a snapshot function which you can use in this way to save a snapshot on HMR:

https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree/blob/a0916791768637665a56bc2720ec0a081d4d148f/packages/mst-example-todomvc/src/index.js#L30-L70